# how to pass a value to a property file from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have created a Jenkins job to run the automation scripts.

I am using `config.properties` file to pass the input parameters to run the script.

My `config.property` file contains below :

```
 browserName=ie
 url=http://google.com
```

Is it possible to set the above parameters from Jenkins job?

Is it possible to do like below :

```
browserName=${BROWSER_NAME}
url=${URL_NAME}
```

Can i pass `"BROWSER_NAME"  &&  "URL_NAME"` value from Jenkins job. if yes, then how?

Please suggest. I am new to Jenkins job configuration.

Comment: Please help if any one knows this

Answer (score 1):

what you can do, is inside your script file, change it to take parameters, 
after that, in you job, you can add a parameters, to be filled by the Jenkins form like "Build with parameters"

Finally, in your run script shell window, add the command to run your script plus the paramters you have filled exemple :

==> $PARAM_ONE (param job jenkins);
script.sh  $PARAM_ONE

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Like Hatim said: "change your script to take parameters" and pass params to your shell script.

But i suppose you want your script to access config.properties and config.properties must be filled with jenkins params?
if so, then you can just echo your jenkins params to this file directly.

1. Set your params in jenkins.

[image]

2. If you want to use complex config than your approach is ok and you can execute shell to insert params from jenkins to a file simply by echoing them and then start your script:
   [image]
3. But if your config.properties is so small, you'd better use script params to make your build config easier. To do that you should modify your .sh script to take parameters from jenkins:

> browserName=$1;url=$2

And then just add your params in execute shell:

[image]

Comment: i will try this today

Comment: Yes i have placeholders in my config.property file and i wants to update the placeholder with the Jenkins value before the script start executing .

Comment: i have already configured the parameters like BROWSER , URL etc.But problem here is how to pass those BROWSER value to placeholders of the config.properties file

Comment: Please suggest here

Comment: @AlokTiwari, I assume you have a config, with a variable already set or not, doesnt matter:
    browserName=ie
    url=http://google.com

So,  i can suggest using sed to update variables: add a build step like i mentioned before in a step 2 and try this:
   sed -i "s|browserName=|$BROWSER_NAME|g" config.properties;
   sed -i "s|browserName=|$URL|g" config.properties

Comment: @AlokTiwari my last answer is just an example, find a way to update your text files, you can use sed,awk or simple bash script to append variable name with replace. GL

Comment: Sure .. Thank you